# mdx datediff error

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, datediff

```
select measures.name on 0,
datediff("d", [Fecha].[Date].currentmember.member_value, [Dim Date].[Date].currentmember.member_value) on 1
from cube
```

> Error: Execution of the managed stored procedure datediff failed with
>   the following error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.Argument 'Date1' cannot be converted to type 'Date'

Is there any requirements to do datediff in mdx? 
In the dimension these member are defined as datetime, not sure if this influence in anyway the result...

Update: I solved the problem by making the calculation at the datasource view and at the cube I added a measure that I could use in MDX to create the indicator that I needed. Of course this is all using SSAS for testing the result and SSDT for creating the members. I hope this approach helps a lot of people even though i don't know if this is the best case scenario. Happy MDX ;)

Comment: What is the type of your member values on ``[Fecha].[Date]``?

Comment: Datetime. Both dimension are "linked" in the cube with the table DimDate

Answer (score 0):

By default, the axis will show, not the member_value, but the member name, which is always a string. The Member_Value is a measure.

```
With Member MyDateDiff as
  datediff("d", [Fecha].[Date].currentmember.member_value, [Dim Date].[Date].currentmember.member_value)
Select 
  (Measures.MyDateDiff, Measures.Name) on 0
  (Fecha.Date.Members, [Dim Date].[Date].Members) on 1
From cube
```

**EDIT**

I'm still new to this too, but after your comments, I thought I should elaborate on the process I went through to get similar queries right.

First, make sure you are getting the data you think you are. Get those Member_Value measures into the Columns dimension:

```
With 
  Member FechaDate as
      [Fecha].[Date].currentmember.member_value
  Member MyDate as
      [Dim Date].[Date].currentmember.member_value
Select 
      (Measures.FechaDate, Measures.MyDate) on 0
      (Fecha.Date.Members, [Dim Date].[Date].Members) on 1
From cube
```

Are you getting date values? If yes, try out your datediff function. If not, check the dimension definitions. I wouldn't be surprised to find the the ValueColumn of one of your attributes was set to the key field instead of the date value field, or some such thing.

Comment: I'm really sorry for my ignorance but can you explain a bit more, I recently started coding with mdx. I'm a little lost. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, me too. It was very frustrating to learn that I couldn't just choose the attribute property that I wanted to see on an axis. The query ALWAYS returns the member_caption when you use it on the ROWS axis. So you have to get the member_value as a separate Member and put it on the Columns axis. I don't know why.

Comment: I see thanks, the approach you suggested me still doesn't work though... When I get to work I'll just add a column in the dsv with the date calculated and add it as a measure in the cube.

Answer (score 0):

You may need two steps, but the date add method should be fine. The Member approach from Bill is good, but it returns it as a string, not a date object. If it's in the correct format, you should be able to do:

```
Member MyDate as
DATEDADD("d", 1, VBAMDX!CDate([Dim Date].[Date].currentmember.member_value))
```

Depending on how your date string ends up formatted, you may have a little more work to do.